# Summation of a formatted column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Example table:

```
ID Calls
1   10
2   20
3   15
4   11
5   09

Output Needed:

  ID Calls  Percent
    1   10    15.38
    2   20    30.77
    3   15    23.08
    4   11    16.92
    5   09    13.85
```

The "Calls" column is already a formatted one. 
`format(count(id),0) as Calls`.

That is the values are found by using formulas. Now I want to make a 3rd column which will show the % value of Calls.

The SUM (Calls) cannot be used as "Calls" is a manual provided name. How should it be done using MySQL query?

Comment: question is not clear post the output you want so It will help you get better answer

Comment: The percentage calculation is unclear, and also can you let us know if the `Calls` column be `varchar`, or is it actually numeric?

Comment: You may want to narrow it down by telling us which RDBMS you're using (MySQL/Oracle/SQL Server/...) to make the question easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If am not wrong you need something like this

If your database supports `window` function.

```
SELECT id,
       calls,
       cast(calls as numeric(15,6)) / NULLIF(Sum(Calls)OVER(), 0)
FROM   yourtable
```

Traditional `SQL` way

```
SELECT id,
       calls,
       calls / NULLIF((SELECT Sum(Calls)
                       FROM   yourtable), 0)
FROM   yourtable
```

Comment: I _think_ the asker is saying `yourtable` is the result of a query, not a table, which makes #2 a bit tricky to write.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Exactly!.. But if `CTE` is supported it will be simpler

Comment: @Ayaz - First tell which **RDBMS** you are using

Comment: @VR46 - I am using MySQL and linked that to Navicat. I am querying it from Navicat.

Comment: Can i do the SUM function on "Calls" ? As it is already a formatted one --> format(count(id),0) as Calls

Comment: Can you add the original query